# Joint and link plugins: do they really exist?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone!

My intention is to write a plugin that will be attached directly to a link or joint, not to the model, in order to apply a force or torque.

I see in this tutorial (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#AddingPlugins) that the `gazebo` tag can accept the `reference` argument, which can be pointed to the link or joint of choice.

However, it is not clear to me what this reference is or where it is accessed by the plugin code.

The standard `Load()` function of the `ModelPlugin` accepts as arguments a `ModelPtr _model` and a `SDFElement _sdf` (for the sdf structure of the plugin tag/environment itself).

How will I go about obtaining the reference link/joint directly?

P.S.
I know that I could pass a `link_name` argument in the plugin and get that from the plugin code, from the `_sdf->GetElement("link_name")`, but this doesn't take advantage of the `reference` tag.

Thank you in advance,
George

edit: Fixed link to point to the correct internal link

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21049/joint-and-link-plugins:-do-they-really-exist?/) by [Georacer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2336/georacer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2018-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe the tutorial is partially wrong. Yes, it is true that you can use a link or a joint as a reference in URDF to inject a plugin tag into it. But there's no point in doing that, because plugins under links and joints are not valid SDF.

See this example URDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="test">

  <link name="link1">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.5"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="joint1" type="revolute">
    <axis xyz="0 -1 0"/>
    <parent link="link1"/>
    <child link="link2"/>
    <limit effort="30" velocity="1.0" lower="-1" upper="1" />
  </joint>

  <link name="link2">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.5"/>
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <!-- OK: model plugin under <robot> ends up under <model> -->
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="model_plugin" filename="model.so">
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- OK: sensor plugin under <gazebo reference="link name"><sensor> ends up under <sensor> -->
  <gazebo reference="link1">
    <sensor type="camera" name="camera">
        <plugin name="sensor_plugin" filename="sensor.so">
        </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- NOT OK: ? plugin under <gazebo reference="link name"> ends up under <link> -->
  <gazebo reference="link2">
    <plugin name="link_plugin" filename="link.so">
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- NOT OK: ? plugin under <gazebo reference="joint name"> ends up under <joint> -->
  <gazebo reference="joint1">
    <plugin name="joint_plugin" filename="joint.so">
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

You can convert it to SDF as follows:

`gz sdf -p test.urdf > test.sdf`

And this is the result:

```
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <model name='test'>
    <link name='link1'>
      ...
      <sensor name='camera' type='camera'>
        <plugin name='sensor_plugin' filename='sensor.so'/>
      </sensor>
    </link>
    <link name='link2'>
      ...
      <plugin name='link_plugin' filename='link.so'/>
    </link>
    <joint name='joint1' type='revolute'>
      ...
      <plugin name='joint_plugin' filename='joint.so'/>
    </joint>
    <plugin name='model_plugin' filename='model.so'/>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

However, that is not valid SDF, since `link_plugin` and `joint_plugin` have no meaning.

So:

1. I think that the parts of the tutorial which encourage inserting plugins under links and joints should be removed.
2. I'm not sure if there's a problem with the URDF -> SDF conversion. The tutorial says that "Any elements inside the  tags which are not (in the spec) are directly inserted into the (relevant) tag of the generated SDF". So it sounds like that's the desired behavior, but I'm not sure why.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2336/georacer/) on 2018-11-14**:
Thank you for your answer! Indeed, I checked again at the SDF documentation and there is no `plugin` tag for `Link` nor for `Joint`. Naturally, there is one for `Sensor`.
It's really frustrating going against bad documentation or tutorials...

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-11-14**:
Glad to help. The tutorial is here, you're welcome to improve it for the community. https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/src/bd2959ec3c617426ecbae2e055776744702dd444/ros_gzplugins/tutorial.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2336/georacer/) on 2018-11-15**:
Did the PR: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/pull-requests/523/re-wrote-the-instructions-to-specify/diff

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are no joint or link plugins. You can use a model plugin to apply forces and torques to links to and joints.

Refer to the [API](http://gazebosim.org/api), and look at [example plugins](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f4e51e8f64001beda70615ab8982a7d5a4e65b18/plugins/?at=default) like [this one](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f4e51e8f64001beda70615ab8982a7d5a4e65b18/plugins/JointControlPlugin.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2018-11-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2336/georacer/) on 2018-11-14**:
I've examined the API and examples dozens of times. The actual question is if this information on passing link and joint references to plugins (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Addingaplugintothe%3Clink%3Eelement) is actually wrong and bad.
Or am I understanding the "reference" argument wrong?